# What could be causing my Ghostscript to fail

Tags: ubuntu, ghostscript

When I run ps2pdf I get the following error messages:

```
norman@host:~$ ps2pdf test.ps test.pdf
While reading gs_dbt_e.ps:
ERROR: /syntaxerror in -file-
Operand stack:
   (gs_cidfm.ps)   1   --nostringval--
Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   %array_continue   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:928/1123(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:74/200(L)--   --dict:928/1123(G)--   --dict:8/8(G)--   --dict:1/1(G)--
Current allocation mode is global
Current file position is 4623
norman@host:~$
```

I have tried re-installing gs and gs-esp without affect.
Files test.ps, gs_dbt_e.ps and gs_cidfm.ps all checked against a working system as being good. Regardless of what postscript file I try to convert, the "Current file position is 4623" remains exactly the same.
The host is running Ubuntu 7.04.

Any suggestions as to what I should re-install will be much appreciated.

Comment: Does `ghostview test.ps` and `gs test.ps` display the file correctly?

Comment: 'ghostview' command not found.  'gs test.ps' gives the same error as ps2pdf.

Comment: I found that if I execute 'gs' without any parameters I still get the same error message.

Answer (score 1):

Which version of Ghostscript do you use on your Ubuntu? You can check with the `gs -v` command. The latest released one is v8.71.

Your problem could come from 2 sources:

1. Your file 'test.ps' contains a bug (invalid PostScript code). Some PS bugs can be worked around by ***some*** viewers and PS processors, some not.
2. Your version of Ghostscript contains a bug that is triggered by some procedure contained in your 'test.ps'.

Without access to your 'test.ps' file, there is no way for me to tell.

I'd recommend you try processing your 'test.ps' with a newer version of Ghostscript. Don't use the `ps2pdf` utility. ps2pdf is just a small shell script that tries to simplify Ghostscript usage for PDF generation, but at the same time leaves a lot of Ghostscripts power behind.

Rather use `gs` directly. Like this:

```
gs \
  -sDEVICE=pdfwrite \
  -dNOPAUSE \
  -dBATCH \
  -dSAFER \
  -sCompatibilityLevel=1.4 \
  -dPDFSETTINGS=/prepress \
  -sOutputFile=/path/to/test.pdf \
  -c ".setpdfwrite" \
  -f /path/to/test.ps
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply, pipitas. The gs version is "ESP Ghostscript 8.15.4 (2007-03-14)". My test.ps file converts without error on other systems running the same version of gs.

An fsck of the hard disk volume reported and repaired about 30 file allocation table errors. So no doubt something is corrupted.

I re-installed gs and gs-esp. What other programs or libraries should I re-install?

I did recommend to the user a complete update of the Linux, but they have not done so yet.

Comment: If not even a command `gs -h` works without spitting out an error, then surely your gs installation (or your harddisk) is corrupted somehow.

Comment: To find out which are the dependent .so files, you can run the 'list dynamic dependencies' command:  `ldd $(which gs)`. This list will show you what libraris `gs` needs to run, and also where it found them (or not). With that list of files you can figure which other packages you may need to re-install. (Or run `dpkg-query -s ghostscript | grep -i depends`.)